# DB Data migration

Tags: database, data-migration

I have a database table called A and now i have create a new table called B and create some columns of A in table B.

Eg: Suppose following columns in tables

Table A // The one already exists

```
Id, Country Age Firstname, Middlename, Lastname
```

Table B // The new table I create

```
Id Firstname Middlename Lastname
```

Now the table A will be look like,

Table A // new table A after the modification

```
Id, Country, Age, Name
```

In this case it will map with table B..

So my problem is now i need to kind of maintain the reports which were generated before the table modifications and my friend told me you need to have a data migration..so may i know what is data migration and how its work please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I forgot to address the reporting issue raised by the OP (Thanks [Mark Bannister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359040/mark-bannister)). Here is a stab at how to deal with reporting.

In the beginning (before data migration) a report to generate the name, country and age of users would use the following SQL (more or less):

```
-- This query orders users by their Lastname
SELECT Lastname, Firstname, Age, Country FROM tableA order by Lastname;
```

The name related fields are no longer present in `tableA` post data migration. We will have to perform a join with `tableB` to get the information. The query now changes to:

```
SELECT b.Lastname, b.Firstname, a.Country, a.Age FROM tableA a, tableB b
WHERE a.name = b.id ORDER BY b.Lastname;
```

I don't know how exactly you generate your report but this is the essence of the changes you will have to make to get your reports working again.

**Original Answer**

Consider the situation when you had only one table (`table A`). A couple of rows in the table would look like this:

```
# Picture 1
# Table A
------------------------------------------------------
Id | Country | Age | Firstname | Middlename | Lastname
1  | US      | 45  | John      | Fuller     | Doe
2  | UK      | 32  | Jane      | Margaret   | Smith
```

After you add the second table (`table B`) the name related fields are moved from `table A` to `table B`. `Table A` will have a foreign key pointing to the `table B` corresponding to each row.

```
# Picture 2
# Table A
------------------------------------------------------
Id | Country | Age | Name
1  | US      | 45  | 10
2  | UK      | 32  | 11

# Table B
------------------------------------------------------
Id | Firstname | Middlename | Lastname
10 | John      | Fuller     | Doe
11 | Jane      | Margaret   | Smit
```

This is the final picture. The catch is that the data will not move from `table A` to `table B` on its own. Alas human intervention is required to accomplish this. If I were the said human I would follow the steps given below:

1. Create `table B` with columns `Id`, `Firstname`, `Middlename` and `Lastname`. You now have two tables `A` and `B`. `A` has all the existing data, `B` is empty .
2. Add a foreign key to `table A`. This FK will be called `name` and will reference the  `id` field of `table B`.
3. For each row in `table A` create a new row in `table B` using the `Firstname`, `Middlename` and `Lastname` fields taken from `table A`.
4. After copying each row, update the `name` field of `table A` with the `id` of the newly created row in `table B`.

The database now looks like this:

```
# Table A
-------------------------------------------------------------
Id | Country | Age | Firstname | Middlename | Lastname | Name
1  | US      | 45  | John      | Fuller     | Doe      | 10
2  | UK      | 32  | Jane      | Margaret   | Smith    | 11

# Table B
------------------------------------------------------
Id | Firstname | Middlename | Lastname
10 | John      | Fuller     | Doe
11 | Jane      | Margaret   | Smith
```

5. Now you no longer need the `Firstname`, `Middlename` and `Lastname` columns in `table A` so you can drop them.
6. voilà, you have performed a data migration!

The process I just described above is but a specific example of a data migration. You can accomplish it in a number of ways using a number of languages/tools. The choice of mechanism  will vary from case to case.

Comment: +1 Good summary of data migration - but doesn't address Harshana's reporting issue.

Comment: That was fast -  I was entering my own summary of approaching the report modifications at tthe same time!

Answer (score 2):

Maintenance of the existing reports will depend on the tools used to write / generate those reports. In general:

1. Identify the existing reports that used table A. (Possibly by searching for files that have the name of table A inside them - however, if table A has a name [eg. Username] which is commonly used elsewhere in the system, this could return a lot of false positives.)
2. Identify which of those reports used the columns that have been removed from table A.
3. Amend the existing reports to return the moved columns from table B instead of table A.

A quick way to achieve this is to create a database view that mimics the old structure of table A, and amend the affected reports to use the database view instead of table A. However, this adds an extra layer of complexity into maintaining the reports (since developers may need to maintain the database view as well as the reports) and may be deprecated or even blocked by the DBAs - consequently, I would only recommend using this approach if a **lot** of existing reports are affected.